# draw inner shadow pipe with paper.js

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, paperjs

I want to draw a inner shadow pipe with paper.js, this is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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). In addition to the shadow effect in the first part, how to achieve the shadow effect in other parts?

Answer (score 0):

just for note, check this [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.15/S/7Vddb9owFP0rFi+BNdAQysNStZO2t2mVJu1hmygPJnaJRbAzxymgiv++azsfzsc+qk1THxaJyvY59/hen/hCn0Yc7+koGn3aURUnI38UC6Lnj1giIdmWcXSD0Dib+ygLfXSYoJtb9HQv7zmCR7MeaayEBFYWoinK5tcumDOuIcuZndAlGt9hlczyb1KNy9UjeoXq4UXDrVdPk0lLNBa5Fm2C/ooqoanCX9xkb1GA3qDpAfRDiDO1RMid9gW+NgLHUqAKMGlHjZ6e1wKSqkJyOD44Q04P6KNgXI1tTn4pPdHks/5Tfey2uWIcKya0Vf+d+ndOXTzDKdcxCL1xQq+CwEfzILBFGkLYIiw1YdkiLPqEtsJVi/C6RzgAvgyue6mBOXV2MB6vqvcpW8Dnam0VDG2WKyl29J1IzUvlbSU+eT34MyMqAfhgkMtL1IrFmY6UouCkH/pemO4zACeYiMPbtND7hsuOsgHrrDYpjnf94CG84WxSyskddELNyEUhYzoVhWposJvHhdzj1PORty9SxbL0pMd5LCnlMKpo4pHKFFtMPKhpyraJ0rMESzJF9TTWGU2JIFvqRNvVDbxxmkOw3Blxz4TZIWEPD1RSHus4jx7jtMihGTgiSWGgHMObaxqFUSj2jIucqVO9ux5gQgy32CiJY8isEsFQBza5eRnjTRmcbmvN6qiA6kyZm4tzmg0DK5GZUppeVou4ay2lFtnKuUuVpj0pWR+ftOVmpuwjFO14Gguei5TOUrEde/brD1h24HTWyRDd2dvz3a48EDh0f55KrHrgOhFGuYp6iH5yqC6P0GoF147qUoK1j1beIWFKWxTMlmZegvP1uqNx9jsLtsioX2yX6FQW/aDMMuLsnGxZMU2h41IC5SpZ0Fb7cchVJwqdTjT7wDgd2040cW982O9D+gIOUQZ7UdjNqsRqWGQ4hlsCKJxqFxzoY51ihnJ8YV6X7f05XtchXa87Fi76FpovkpaFi19buPiZhYs/sHDxmxZ2c3xhFppDfZ6FdciQhfCfwEZSvMv074d8FK3W5+8=)